# node.js express app can't find jade view, 404 message responded

Tags: node.js, express, pug

for my app i use node.js as backend and Express as framework. I use Netbeans as IDE and i get the following output.

```
Not Found
404

Error: Not Found
at /home/ingeborg/netbeans/GML/app.js:33:13
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ingeborg/netbeans/GML/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/ingeborg/netbeans/GML/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /home/ingeborg/netbeans/GML/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (/home/ingeborg/netbeans/GML/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/home/ingeborg/netbeans/GML/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at /home/ingeborg/netbeans/GML/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
at next (/home/ingeborg/netbeans/GML/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)
at Function.handle (/home/ingeborg/netbeans/GML/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
at router (/home/ingeborg/netbeans/GML/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
```

I have the following data setup:

```
- node-modules
- public
    - fonts
    - images
    - javascripts 
    - stylesheets
        stylesheets.less
        stylesheet.css
    - routes
        index.js
        news.js
        users.js
    - views
        index.jade
        error.jade
        news.jade
        layout.jade
    Gruntfile.js
    app.js
    gulpfile.js
    package.json
```

the app.js looks like this

```
var news  = require('./routes/news');
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var app = express();
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
...
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/index', index);
app.use('/news', news);
app.use('/users', users);
```

and this is my index.jade

```
h3 
  a(href="news") link
```

and this my news.jade

```
h3 test
```

.

The routing is realised over route files. 
index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

router.get('/index', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});
module.exports = router;
```

the news.js router file is

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('news', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('news');
});
module.exports = router;
```

The following circumstances are

- the routing on the links "/" and "index" works as wanted.
- the routing on "/news" or "news" (tested in the rounting, app.js and view file) not. I have no clue why the routing isn't working. I hope i haven't forgotten sth.

Thx, 
Inge

Answer (score 2):

Your code works for me.

**/app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var news  = require('./routes/news');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/news', news);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**/routes/news.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('news');
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: which IDE u used?

Comment: I use Sublime Text. The above example was created by the express cli generator `express --view=jade myapp` https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Comment: got it now. The "/" was missed in the jade file after i removed "/news" just to "/". Thx alot for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

The news route file is missing. There you have to render your jade.

```
var news  = require('./routes/news');
```

Comment: in app.js? It is the first line or does it belong to another place?

Comment: you specify on app.js to use the file /routes/news.js for all /news routes, but in your data setup list the news.js file is missing in the routes folder.

Comment: The 2nd thing i just saw is that you are routing twice to /news/news, once in the app.js over app.use('/news', news); and the 2nd time over the news.js file router.get('news', function(req, res, next) .. sou you can try to visit http://localhost:3000/news/news or change the router.get('news'... to router.get('/'... in your news.js.

Comment: done. 404. As comparison take a look to the routes of the index view. There is the same code.

Comment: news.js is in the route file. was  a mistake by me. It is part of the setup.

Comment: its awkward. i changed all app.use('/....', var1) to app.use('/', var1). index is still running. But news not.